# Extension of DVRs and uniformizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, formal-completions

Let $(A,\mathfrak m)$ be a **regular**, Noetherian, local, domain of dimension $2$ and consider a prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$ of height $1$. Moreover let $\hat{A}$ be the completion of $A$ with respect to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ and consider a prime ideal $\mathfrak P\subset \hat{A}$ such that $\mathfrak P\cap A=\mathfrak p$

The localizations $A_\mathfrak p$  and $\hat{A}_{\mathfrak P}$ are discrete valuation rings, and the canonical immersion $A\to \hat{A}$ induces a local injective homomorphism:

$$f:A_\mathfrak p\to\hat{A}_{\mathfrak P}$$

The following result is true but I don't understand the reason, please help me:

> A uniformizer element $\pi$ of $A_\mathfrak p$ is also
>   a uniformizer of $\hat{A}_{\mathfrak P}$

I think that in this case one should prove that the extension of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$ through $f$ is equal to $\mathfrak P A_{\mathfrak P}$...

**Note:** The result is quoted without proof in a paper, I don't mention the source because it doesn't matter. It is a technical detail in the proof of a bigger theorem.

Comment: I mean injective homomorphism.... It is abuse of language

Comment: Why is $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ a dvr, unless you assume something about $A$?

Comment: $A$ is regular, I forgot to say it... I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about general Noetherian rings, but at least in the geometric case, this follows from the fact that the completion of a reduced ring is reduced (one of the proofs is due to Zariski). Assuming this, in your case $\mathfrak{p}=\pi A$ and then $\pi\in \widehat{A}$ is product of distinct prime elements. Then $\mathfrak{P}$ is generated by one of these primes and the rest should be clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately I still don't understand the last line. Ok,  $\mathfrak P$ is generated by a prime factor of $\pi$ in $\hat{A}$... and so? How do you conclude?

Comment: So, when you localize at that prime, the other prime factors become units and so $\pi$ is the this particular prime factor upto a unit in this local ring, and thus $\pi$ generates this prime ideal.

Comment: @Mohan Sorry for the intromission. Even if the OP has accepted the answer in my opinion there is something not clear. First of all in the question he says that $A$ is a domain, so why do you point out that it should be reduced? Then, why is $\pi$ a product of DISTINCT primes? If  all powers in the decomposition of $\pi$ (in $\hat{A}$) are $\ge 2$ I fear that your proof fails...

Comment: I mean, suppose for example that $\pi=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^2$, then $\pi\in \mathfrak P^2$..

Comment: I am not applying the result of Zariski to $A$, but to $A/\pi A$. Zariski implies the completion  is reduced (and may not be a domain), but this is $\widehat{A}/\pi\widehat{A}$ and this implies $\pi$ is a product of distinct primes in $\widehat{A}$.

Comment: Yes, now I see it. Sorry for bothering you.